# Add Classes to an SVG element after using PHP's file_get_contents

Tags: php, html, svg

I need to fetch an SVG image and insert the image onto a page. I am fetching the image using:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("logo.svg"); ?>
```

which outputs something like

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"">
    <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486"></path>
</svg>
```

How would I go about adding a class to the SVG element after inserting onto the page? As in:

```
<svg class="LogoStyle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"">
    <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486"></path>
</svg>
```

or targeting to the path element:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"">
    <path class="LogoStyle" d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486"></path>
</svg>
```

Any help would be nice, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store your `svg` as a PHP variable and then use the DOMDocument() feature to accomplish this.

```
$svg = file_get_contents("logo.svg");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($svg);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('svg') as $element) {
    $element->setAttribute('class','new-classname-goes-here');  
}
$dom->saveHTML();
$svg = $dom->saveHTML();    
echo $svg;
```

To target the `path` instead of the `svg` element, simply update the `getElementsByTagName('svg')` to `getElementsByTagName('path')`.

Comment: Unless you want an invalid tag warning, you'll need to use `loadXML()` instead of `loadHTML()`. Line 3 should read `$dom->loadXML($svg);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery` to add class to an element after inserting onto the page.

```
$('svg').addClass('LogoStyle');
```

Comment: Makes sense, I was sort of hoping there might be a way to fetch the SVG file and include the Class name into the DOM with PHP. I guess this is about as straightforward a way to do it as any though.